# Is it possible to start celery when FastAPI is started

Tags: python, celery, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a simple FastAPI implementation set up as well as a Celery task queue. I would just like to call the uvicorn command and have celery start as well, for example, by including a celery task worker start command in main.py. Is this possible?